# GUFW returns a segmentation fault in line 13

Tags: ufw, segmentation-fault

When I run GUFW as root, it returns:

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_modifier_mask: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(gufw.py:5272): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_replace_virtual_modifiers: assertion 'GDK_IS_KEYMAP (keymap)' failed
/usr/bin/gufw-pkexec: line 13:  5272 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python3 ${LOCATIONS[${i}]} $1
```

It crashes due to a segmentation fault, even though this is a fresh install of a stable GUFW build.

How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type the following command in a terminal:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

If it returns `Wayland`, type:

```
xhost si:localuser:root
```

to allow root to start graphical apps under Wayland sessions.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, but it doesn't persist after a reboot.  Hopefully this will be resolved with Debian 11 since it's just around the corner.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/gufw-segmentation-fault/46756/32), I had the same problem running Manjaro KDE. Simply changing this, worked correctly:

```
/etc/sddm.conf
DefaultPath=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

The explanation, in the cited thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Accidentally found the solution for gparted over SSH [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477732/run-gparted-over-ssh).

```
sudo -E gufw
```

This should work - assuming /etc/ssh/sshd_config is properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the executable is run using `pkexec`, as you can see from the contents of `/usr/sbin/gufw`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(loginctl show-session $(loginctl|grep $(whoami)|sort -n|tail -n 1 |awk '{print $1}') -p Type) = "Type=wayland" ]; then
    xhost +si:localuser:root
fi
c_user=$(whoami)
pkexec gufw-pkexec $c_user
```

Reading the manual page for `pkexec`, says:

> The environment that PROGRAM will run it, will be set to a minimal
> known and safe environment in order to avoid injecting code through
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar mechanisms. In addition the
> PKEXEC_UID environment variable is set to the user id of the process invoking pkexec. As a result, **pkexec will not by default allow
> you to run X11 applications as another user since the
> $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY environment variables are not set**. These two variables will be retained if the
> org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui annotation on an action is
> set to a nonempty
> value; this is discouraged, though, and should only be used for legacy programs.

So basically, if you are trying to run `gufw` on an X11 system, this command won't work. However, if you directly do:

```
sudo gufw-pkexec
```

It works. Smh

---

#### EDIT

Found a solution at a [bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/66556) on the arch package. Basically, the path set in the polkit policy file for gufw (`/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.ubuntu.pkexec.gufw.policy`) used the wrong path for the executable.

I changed:

```
<annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/gufw-pkexec</annotate>
```

to

```
<annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/sbin/gufw-pkexec</annotate>
```

And now it works